# Освобождает ли динамическую память деструктор с пустым телом?

Tags: pascal, delphi

Освобождает ли динамическую память деструктор с пустым телом?

Answer (score 1):

И да, и нет. Если в конструкторе понавыделять памяти, то кто то ее должен почистить. Пустой деструктор это не сделает.
Но если не добавить inherited, то не будут вызваны деструкторы предков. А это ещё утечки.